# Monotouch Tell Difference Between iPad 3G and WiFi (Check for GPS)

Tags: c#, objective-c, mono, xamarin.ios, gps

I currently have some objective C code which I use to identify the difference between an iPad 3G and an iPad WiFi.  Bizarrely both models come under the device code iPad1,1 (iPad 2s have three different codes iPad2,1 iPad2,2 and iPad2,3 which allows you to tell the difference).

So the code I use to tell the difference between iPad 1st Gen models, checks for presence of the GPS functionality using the following code:

```
void *libHandle = dlopen(GRAPHICS_SERVICES_PATH, RTLD_LAZY);
int (*GSSystemHasCapability)(NSString *);
GSSystemHasCapability = dlsym(libHandle, "GSSystemHasCapability");
BOOL result = GSSystemHasCapability(@"gps");
dlclose(libHandle);
```

Being quite new to Monotouch I am unsure how to port this across.  Does anyone have any pointers as to how to port this (or any other way to tell the difference)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bizarrely both models come under the device code iPad1,1 (iPad 2s have three different codes iPad2,1 iPad2,2 and iPad2,3 which allows you to tell the difference).

Yes, when downloading updates there's always a single binary for the first generation iPad.

> So the code I use to tell the difference between iPad 1st Gen models, checks for presence of the GPS functionality using the following code:

Be **warned** that the above ObjectiveC code will likely be rejected by Apple if you wish your application to be available in the AppStore. That's because the feature you're looking at is part of a **private** framework.

```
#define GRAPHICS_SERVICES_PATH  "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices"
```

If you want to use this (e.g. a non-AppStore application) then you should be able to p/invoke into the function using:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

[DllImport ("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices")]
static extern bool GSSystemHasCapability (IntPtr value);

...

bool HasGPS ()
{
    using (NSString gps = new NSString ("gps"))
        return GSSystemHasCapability (gps.Handle);
}
```

**UPDATE** It seems the only (valid for AppStore) way to detect the GPS is to use the location services and query it's accuracy. See: [How can I tell if an iOS device has a GPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141719/how-can-i-tell-if-an-ios-device-has-a-gps)

Comment: Amazing, thank you.  I know this is a private framework but I have used it successfully in four App Store published apps to date with no issues.  I am not suggesting anyone else uses it as I know it might never make it past the next approval, but until then it works well for my needs! Thanks again. Oli

Comment: Note that using `dlopen`, `dlsym` and `dlclose` *could* be hiding the symbol from Apple tools (which allowed you to pass the AppStore check). YMMV :)

Comment: Interesting!  Do you think it is likely that that is the case?  Don't suppose you can think of another way to tell a 3G from a WiFi (without this framework?)

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative / link. It has the advantage of telling you if the GPS is presently usable (not just available) which can be more useful (at least for some applications).